# Returning a record with a string in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frameworks, ember-data

I am trying to implement a search function where a user can return other users by passing a username through a component. I followed the ember guides and have the following code to do so in my routes file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  flashMessages: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    searchAccount (params) {
      // let accounts = this.get('store').peekAll('account');
      // let account = accounts.filterBy('user_name', params.userName);
      // console.log(account);

      this.get('store').peekAll('account')
      .then((accounts) => {
        return accounts.filterBy('user_name', params.userName);
      })
      .then((account) => {
        console.log(account);
        this.get('flashMessages')
        .success('account retrieved');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.get('flashMessages')
        .danger('There was a problem. Please try again.');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This code, however, throws me the following error:

`"You cannot pass '[object Object]' as id to the store's find method"`

I think that this implementation of the `.find` method is no longer valid, and I need to go about returning the object in a different manner. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You said you followed ember guides but where did it mention to use find method. `find` is a private method so don't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `.then` for `filterBy`.

You can't do `.then` for `peekAll`. because both will not return the Promise.

Calling asynchronous code and inside the `searchAccount` and returning the result doesn't make much sense here. since `searchAccount` will return quickly before completion of async code.

```
this.get('store').findAll('account',{reload:true}).then((accounts) =>{
 if(accounts.findBy('user_name', params.userName)){
  // show exists message
 } else {
  //show does not exist message
 }
});
```

the above code will contact the server, and get all the result and then do findBy for the filtering. so filtering is done in client side.  instead of this you can do query,

```
this.store.query('account', { filter: { user_name: params.userName } }).then(accounts =>{
 //you can check with length accounts.length>0
 //or you accounts.get('firstObject').get('user_name') === params.userName
 //show success message appropriately.
});
```

Comment: Your first implementation ended up working for me, allowing me to pull the account I was looking for and query its properties. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

DS.Store#find is not a valid method in modern versions of Ember Data. If the users are already in the store, you can peek and filter them:

```
this.store.peekAll('account').filterBy('user_name', params.userName);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use the same approach you used in your earlier question, and `query` them (assuming your backend supports filtering):

```
this.store.query('account', { filter: { user_name: params.userName } });
```

Comment: I tried implementing this code, but it keeps breaking and throwing an error reading `TypeError: this.get(...).peekAll(...).then is not a function at Class.searchAccount`. I can split the two up, but running filterBy fails to catch any data. What do you think is causing these errors, and how can I go about fixing them?

Comment: @d00medman Ah, duh, `peekAll` doesn't return a promise. I'll fix my example solution.